# adding child inside function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My task is to add h1 inside the div with input and button after clicking it. I don`t know if it is possible to add child inside function and if it is not how else i can do this

```
import React from "react";

class ToDo extends React.Component {
  addTask() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("input").value;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="input" type="text" ref={input => (this.textInput = input)} />
        <button onClick={this.addTask}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToDo;
```

Comment: Do you want to add a new `h1` inside your `div` each time you press the button?

Comment: do you use jsx?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ToDo extends React.Component {
  state = {expanded: false};

  render() {
    const {expanded} = this.state;

    if(expanded) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>
            <input .../>
          </h1>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({expanded: false})>cancel</button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
        return <div onClick={() => this.setState({expanded: true})>add task</div>
    }
  }
}
```

I left the internal "schematic", you need to add your elements and handler, just wanted to demonstrate the principal